# The time derivative of a vector not defined in terms of the time variable $t$

Tags: kinematics, vectors, differentiation, calculus

Recently I got a question where I needed to determine the time derivative of a position vector. However, the vector didn’t have the variable $t$ but instead had $x$, $y$, and $z$ as its terms, so I was confused:

Ex.  $$\mathbf{r}=x\hat{i}+5y^2\hat{j}+10z^2\hat{k}$$

How can I derive this vector in terms of time when the vector itself is not defined in terms of $t$?

Answer (score 1):

In such a case the only thing you can do is to differentiate vector to write them in terms of component derivative. Here what I mean
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{r}=\frac{dx}{dt}\hat{i}+10y\frac{dy}{dt}\hat{j}+20z\frac{dz}{dt}\hat{k}$$
or
$$\dot{\mathbf{r}}=\dot{x}\hat{i}+10y\dot{y}\hat{j}+20z\dot{z}\hat{k}$$
That's all you can do in such a cases unless you have given some additional information.